# What is difference between LineString and MultiLineString?

Tags: qgis, multipart

What is the difference between Linestring and multiline string, and things like compound curve, curve polygon, multicurve, and multisurface?

Answer (score 3):

Any geographical object can be made of a random number of 'sub-parts'.

**That applies for point, line or polygonal objects**.

When you click in the attribute table you select **only one object** (=one row) but its geometry can be made of several parts (these sub-parts being contiguous **or not** ...)

You can check the multipart objects of a given table using (for example) the **num_geometries** function in QGIS
(by adding a calculated field using the following syntax : `num_geometries(geometry)`)